# How to setup the iOS Simulator with iOS 7 to make advertisingTrackingEnabled return NO?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

How can I setup the iOS Simulator with iOS 7 such that [advertisingTrackingEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ASIdentifierManager/advertisingTrackingEnabled) returns NO instead of the standard YES ?